# Border is disappearing when converting HTML document to PDF

Tags: html, css

I have a JS file to generate HTML document.
When users right-click, click print and save as PDF, the border of the document is disappearing before the document ends.

Code:

```
div {
        margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
```

HTML document image:

[image]

PDF document image:

[image]

Comment: Try with min-height: 100%. Because the vh metric probably omits the scroll size below and that could cause the issue.

Comment: It could be that your border is too thin. Try to zoom in the file in your PDF Viewer and see if the line appears. Sometimes PDF Viewers hide a line that's too thin.

Comment: @dbonev I changed from vh to % but it's still the same

Comment: @ninadepina I changed the border px but it keeps disappearing in the same place :(

Comment: Could you put just enough code into your question so that we can experience the problem? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14190) helps

Comment: Incredibly, it's not the code, it's Google Chrome that is giving this conflict, I tested it in other browsers and it worked perfectly, thanks for the answers!